# Monolith to Separate Services Help and Guidance

Tags: restful-architecture, microservices

I'm in the process of breaking a monolith into separate microservices. I already have a contact service - it stores Names, Email Addresses, Phone Numbers etc.

I want to create another service for organisations/businesses. These organisations have contacts so I'd like to use my existing Contact Service for this rather than recreating it all.

Can anyone advise on how I should structure this? I've thought of the following two ways.

1) Implement the Contact Service within the Org Service. So a user of the Org service is unaware the contact service is separate. This has the drawback that I need to recreate a load of endpoints in the Org service that simply (more or less) pass through to the contact service.

2) Let the user of these services create a contact through the contact service and then just create a way to 'attach' this contact to the organisation.

Is one of these preferable? Or is there another way I've not thought of?

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there another way I've not thought of?

3) Add the organisation to Contact domain model.

To me, both contacts and organisations naturally fall under the same "Contact" or "CRM" business domain.

Put another way, if you were to remove the Contacts Service, would the Organisation Service be able to do any useful work? If not, then this may be a signal that you should simply make Organisation a part of the Contact business domain.

This appears especially true as one of the options you outline the organisation service is just serving as a facade onto the contacts service. If there is no material difference between the Contact model in the Contact service and the representation of that model in the Organisation service, then they are effectively interchangeable and so should not be separated.